# cellcolor in array LaTeX

Tags: spacing, arrays, cellcolor

The gray shading in the cells leaves no white space on the left. Can somebody help me to solve that problem?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
$\left(\begin{array}{ccccc|r}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 &1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{lightgray}{-1}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{lightgray}{4}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{lightgray} {-2} 
\end{array}\right)$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

How about this?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
$\left(\begin{array}{ccccc|lr}                                                  
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & &1 \\                                                       
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & &\cellcolor{lightgray}{-1}\\                                
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & &\cellcolor{lightgray}{4}\\                                 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & &\cellcolor{lightgray}{-2}                                  
\end{array}\right)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I think that It solves the problem!

Answer (score 4):

A solution by using the padding of `\columncolor`.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
$\left(\begin{array}{ccccc|>{\columncolor{lightgray}[1mm]}r}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2  
\end{array}\right)$
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]